# PowerShell: run Python script from Azure blob storage

Tags: python, powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am brand new to using PowerShell and all I want to do is create a .ps1 file that I can execute which then executes a python script from blob storage in my Azure storage account.

I think the normal execution command would simply be:

```
C:/test.py
```

or maybe set the path then:

```
python test.py
```

???

But how do I do this to execute a script stored in a blob at say:

```
https://StorageName.blob.core.windows.net/testing/testblob/test.py
```

?

And can I just save that command as a .ps1 which will kickoff the Python script when I execute the .ps1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd first need to download your python script from your blob to local storage (whether local = VM, web/worker role instance, website instance, your laptop...). Then, once it's downloaded, you can run it.

And since you're using PowerShell: If you install the Azure PowerShell cmdlets, you can download the file from blob, using `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent`:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container containername -Blob blobname -Destination localFolder
```

More info on `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent).